# getMetricData is not using assumed role?

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-js

Im trying to get some cloudwatch /rda metrics with the aws-sdk

since the user Im using don't have enough permission to access cloudwatch resources, I need to assume a role at first and it seems to be ok.

```
sts.assumeRole(paramsts, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log("Cannot assume role. Received the following error: " +err.stack);
  else { 
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    }); 
  console.log(data)
```

it return me a token
with what seems to be the proper creds

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'XXXXXXX' },
  Credentials:
   { AccessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXX',
     SecretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXX',
     SessionToken:
      'mytoken',
     Expiration: sometimes soon },
  AssumedRoleUser:
   { AssumedRoleId: 'blablabla',
     Arn:
      'arn:aws:sts::numbers:assumed-role/myroles' } }
```

now when in the call back of this I use getMetricData its not returning me any data. Im always getting the same answer even if Im searching for non existing item

```
cw.getMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);

  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

it always output me this:

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'XXXXx' },
  MetricDataResults:
   [ { Id: 'freestorage',
       Label: 'FreeStorageSpace',
       Timestamps: [],
       Values: [],
       StatusCode: 'Complete',
       Messages: [] }, ] }
```

it seems that the role is not properly assumed when Im using getMetricData. Am i missing something?

Im able to fectch the data from the cli when assuming the same role  with the same parameters but this piece of code always return me 0 values/datapoint.